# what is the qtransform in QGraphicsScene::itemAt()

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I create a custom `QGraphicsItem`. And overwrite the `boundingRect()` and `paint()`.

```
QRectF myTile::boundingRect() const
{
  return QRectF(xPos*10, yPos*10, 10, 10);
}

void myTile::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
  QRectF rec = boundingRect();
  int gvi = value * 255;
  QColor gv(gvi, gvi, gvi, 255);
  QBrush brush(gv);
  painter->fillRect(rec, brush);
  painter->drawRect(rec);
}
```

Then I use `addItem()` to add a item to a scene. Now I want to get it from the scene by its position. I find the `itemAt` function. But the problem is I don't know what is the `const QTransform` & `deviceTransform`. What should I use for the `QTransform`?.

Because I didn't implement any transform in the `QGraphicsItem`. This confuses me.

Answer (score 5):

```
QGraphicsItem * QGraphicsScene::itemAt ( const QPointF & position, const QTransform & deviceTransform ) const
```

> Returns the topmost visible item at the specified position, or 0 if
>   there are no items at this position. `deviceTransform` is the
>   transformation that applies to the view, and needs to be provided if
>   the scene contains items that ignore transformations. This function
>   was introduced in Qt 4.6.

So I would say, if you have the need to transform some items and ignore the others, you can simply go with the default value of `QTransform()` or even better the `QGraphicsView::transform() const`.

soo long zai

Comment: Mind though that a QGraphicsScene can have more than one view. So the value of `deviceTransform` depends on the context. For example, in a mouse event handler you'd have to figure out from which view the event came from. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919819/itemat-not-returning-custom-qgraphicsitem#comment24426364_16921083).